# How to add formula like "IF(A1="","",A1) in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add `IF(A1="","",A1)` in VBA using

```
Activesheet.Range("A1").Formula = "IF(A1="","",A1)"
```

If anyone know to use this formula in VBA, please help.

Comment: Does your formula fail to work? What seems to go wrong?

Comment: I'm assuming that your example is partially made up, but assigning a formula to `A1` that refers to `A1` will cause circular reference issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it is the quotation marks you have trouble entering into the formula? When constructing a string, you can either use double quotation marks to enter one into the string, like this:

```
Activesheet.Range("A1").Formula = "=IF(A1="""","""",A1)"
```

Or you can construct the string inserting the quotation with the [`Chr`-method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264465.aspx) like this:

```
Activesheet.Range("A1").Formula = "=IF(A1=" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ",A1)"
```

For an overview of what `Chr`-numbers correspond to what characters, you can e.g. have a look [here](http://www.gtwiki.org/mwiki/?title=VB_Chr_Values).

Comment: Don't forget to add an equal sign before the if. Should be `Activesheet.Range("A1").Formula = "=IF(A1="""","""",A1)"`

Comment: Ah, yeah, the dangers of copypasta. Have edited it in now :)

Comment: @BunrithHeng Great :) If this is the answer you prefer, I would appreciate it if you marked it as such (there should be a checkmark next to the top of the answer).

Answer (score 1):

Use a different character for quotes, like "?", then replace that character with quotes.

```
dim strFormula as string

formula = "=IF(A1=??,??,A1)"
formula = Replace(formula,"?",Chr(34))

Activesheet.Range("A1").Formula = strFormula
```

Comment: Don't forget to add an equal sign before the if. Should be `formula = "=IF(A1=??,??,A1)"`

Comment: I do like the approach. Certainly makes it easier to read